# Google Maps API onInfoWindowClick getTitle for all markers, not just one

Tags: android, json, google-maps

I've successfully made "Keating Hall" open up a new activity, however my list of locations (Markers are populated via external JSON file and names are ready into strings).

I'd like to make it so all my locations InfoWindows are sent to my OptionsActivity, not exclusive to "Keating Hall".

Here's some code that deals with the OnInfoWindowClickListener with the hard coded value:

```
private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    if (map == null) {
        map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();
        if (map != null) {
            setUpMap();

            // allows info windows to be clicked on and open OptionsActivity
            map.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker){
                    if(marker.getTitle().equals("Keating Hall")){ // TODO replace Keating Hall       with last marker clicked title
                        Intent info = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), OptionsActivity.class);
                        startActivity(info);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the void function dealing with the JSON array with the titles of each location:

```
void createMarkersFromJson(String json) throws JSONException {
    // De-serialize the JSON string into an array of city objects
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        // Create a marker for each city in the JSON data.
        JSONObject jsonObj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .title(jsonObj.getString("name"))
                        .snippet(Integer.toString(jsonObj.getInt("check ins")))
                        .position(new LatLng(
                                jsonObj.getJSONArray("latlng").getDouble(0),
                                jsonObj.getJSONArray("latlng").getDouble(1)
                        ))

        );
    }
}
```

For the love of all things that are good, I can't figure out what to replace "Keating Hall" with so that all my InfoWindows are sent the Intent to startActivity --> OptionsActivity, not just one of them.

I've gone through a bunch of examples on here, but since I'm using JSON I wasn't able to replicate the changes needed to allow my application to work.

Thanks for you help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is a problem in your logic. Either you are not calling setUpMapIfNeeded() or condition in onInfoWindowClick() doesn't satisfy. Debug your code and check all the conditions.

Comment: I'm calling setUpMapIfNeeded. onInfoWindowClick() only satisfies when the string value is hardcoded, i.e. "Keating Hall". I have a JSON array of 40+ names converted to strings, so I'm trying to implement a value to call ALL of the values, perhaps in a for loop that goes from JSONarray value 0-40.

Comment: Let me clarify: 

if(marker.getSnippet().equals("0") 

I want the range of 0 to be 0-62, so all values 0,1,2,...,62 are included.

Answer (score 0):

**Try with this..**

> Also Implements your Activity as

```
implements OnClickListener, GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener

GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener
```

// after that ...set it at on create below given code

```
map.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(this);
```

// After that use this code to get  onInfoWindowClick getTitle for all markers, not just one

```
@Override
        public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker)
        {
    // and used  String m = marker.getId(); or  marker.getTitle() or marker.getSnipet
        }
```

Comment: I wasn't able to get that working. I think I might have an alternate method though. 

in the if(marker.getTitle().equals("title") I could replace that value to equal something between 0-62, which is an int converted to string from my JSON. Could I set it so anything from 0-62 in the JSON is allowed OnInfoWindowClick?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this myself, it was quite easy.

in `setUpMapIfNeeded()` the following will open a new activity for all `onInfoWindowClick`, but if you wanted to hard code it to certain InfoWindow you would uncomment the titles that I have. if `(marker.isVisible()` sets it to open a new activity for all InfoWindows.

```
private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    if (map == null) {
        map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();
        if (map != null) {
            setUpMap();

            // allows info windows to be clicked on and open OptionsActivity
            map.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker){
                    if(marker.isVisible()
                            //|| marker.getTitle().equals("title a")
                            //|| marker.getTitle().equals("title b")
                            //|| marker.getTitle().equals("title c")
                            ){ 
                        Intent info = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), OptionsActivity.class);
                        startActivity(info);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```